# How to filter value 1/1/1601 1:00:00 AM of password last set?

Tags: windows, powershell, ldap, ldap-query

I want to print out the password last set values by using "paswordLastSet" attribute. After implementing some filters as the following:

```
$passwordLS = $user.Properties.Item("pwdLastSet")[0]

if($passwordLS -eq 0)
    {         
         $value = "No password last set"
    }
    else
    {
         $value = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($passwordLS)
    }
```

And I got an output:

```
No password last set
2/26/2003 12:21
11/27/2003 11:30
11/27/2003 11:30
1/1/1601 1:00:00 AM
.................
```

As listed above, there is a value "1/1/1601 1:00:00 AM" which means user never set their password. But, I do not want to take this value as my data. I would love to filter it out with "No password last set" instead of giving me "1/1/1601 1:00:00 AM" as an output.

I have investigated this issue to find an element that could help me somehow filter "1/1/1601 1:00:00 AM" , even I tried to print all the values by 100-nanoseconds to get the mutual value for this. Unfortunately, it's all different from each other.

I have also try to give a statement:

```
if($passwordLS -eq 0)
    {         
         $value = "No password last set"
    }
    else
    {
         $value = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($passwordLS)
         if($value -eq "1/1/1601 1:00:00 AM"){

                $value = "No password last set"    
         }
         else{    
                $value = $value
         }
    }
```

But I think it's not a decent code. Any better experience ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is not working is because you are comparing the `datetime` object `$value` to the string `"1/1/1601 1:00:00 AM"`

You have many options - e.g:

- Compare `$value` to `[datetime]` object - for example `$("1/1/1601 01:00:00" | Get-Date)`
- Exclude based on year, without worrying about the reset of date information.

The `Else` setting `$value = $value` is redundant.

Code:

```
if($passwordLS -eq 0)
    {         
         $value = "No password last set"
    }
    else
    {
         $value = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($passwordLS)
         if($value.Year -eq 1601){                           # this one
         if($value -eq $("1/1/1601 01:00:00" | Get-Date)){   # or this one
                $value = "No password last set"    
         }

    }
```

Comment: Thank so much for your help. Actually, as far as my knowledge about Powershell. I think I'm comparing String to String. Because you can see 
**$passwordLS = $user.Properties.Item("pwdLastSet")[0]** is already initialized as a string with [0] in the end?. Hmm, I'm not sure I'm correct or not but it does work in this case. Can you help me to clear away this?. what is the purpose of [0] ?

Comment: @Ender Np. `[0]` is used to index into an array, returning the 1st element. `$passwordLS` is (I believe) a string, but `$value` is definitely `datetime` and that is the one being compared to `"1/1/1601 1:00:00 AM"`. You can see that `$value` is `datetime` by running `$value.GetType()` or checking [the documentation for DateTime.FromFileTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromfiletime(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Oh my words, okay.. it was too hasty in this case. I got it. My bad.. Btw, Tks so much for your help, I got it working now :D . have a nice day!